# Singular vs plural following "noun[s]+of+noun"

Tags: nouns

I wish to correct my understanding.  I found this example:

> The claimant must prove that **the particulars of claim** ***has*** been served on the defendant.

The particulars of claim are one document consisting of several pages.

However, there should be 'have' not 'has' immediately after 'claim' because of 'particulars'.

Am I correct?

Kind regards,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an obscure legal usage that bears no relation to current English syntax.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  is it not worthwhile to point out that it is obscure, and should not be emulated?  At least that way if someone else comes across the phrase, they know better.

Comment: I totally disagree.  The questions like this one, at least, helps to progress in English.  Even if it is legal usage, it is still the English language, and does not become Chinese.   It follows the same grammar rules to which 'current English syntax' is subject. If the legal usage were to be excluded, then the other types of the English language (scientific, political, business, literature) should be excluded too.  Let's also exclude all other types of question that fall outside the commonly used grammar rules and learn English out of the practical context.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad phrase to base generalizations on.

> **Particulars of Claim**
>
> plural noun
>
> law
>
> (in England) the first reading made by the claimant in a county court action, showing the facts upon which he or she relies in support of a claim and the relief asked for
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/particulars-of-claim

*Particulars of Claim* is the proper name of a document and as such, it would be reasonable to treat the phrase as referring to the singular document, rather than the plural contents.

As it turns out, this is not how *particulars of claim* is typically used.  As *Collins* notes, even though it's a proper name, it's used as a plural noun. Other dictionaries agree:

> The particulars of claim **were** filed and served on the defendant (emphasis added)
>
> https://www.translegal.com/legal-english-dictionary/particulars-of-claim

But in other similar examples, where a title or name that appears to be plural, the noun is treated as singular.  For example: "My favorite movie **is** ***Children*** of a Lesser God"

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.